# why does on change listening always go in initialize function for re-rendering

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to understand why we always put event listening type code like, in intialize:

```
initialize: function(){    
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
}
```

I thought the initialize function was only called once when the view way created so it doesn't really make sense why it would go in the initialize function, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone has many built in event listeners, 'change' being one of these. There are a few reasons why you add model listeners inside of the initialize function. Backbone uses jQuery for its eventing system. One of its notable features are creating arbitrary event names. Backbone collections and models come pre-built with existing events (add, create, sync, update, change, etc). These events are not built into the javascript language, thus, during initialization of models and collections in Backbone, you register the events that you would like to intercept and/or listen to.

If you're wondering why can't you just create an update (or any other event listener) method inside of your models and expect Backbone to invoke these automatically is because this would cause a major performance and memory issues.

so... Inside your Backbone views, you must 'subscribe' to events on the model or collection objects your view is bound to. Because Backbone does not have 2-way data binding, it is customary to invoke the 'render' event whenever necessary, which is more often than not when your models or collections update, sync, change, and so on.

Comment: Thanks I have to learn backbone for work and so far it's a little confusing but im starting to get it.